# Why is the useEffect() Hook re-rendering more than 10 times?

Tags: reactjs, render, react-context, react-dom

It looks like my "EnterPin" function re-renders all of the time. I only need to re-render it once when Authentication is true.

When it then changes to /chat it should call two functions. The current problem is that it calls the function more than ten times. I guess the problem might be that the useeffect functions triggers too often? What do you think?

So the wanted result is that it changes to "/chat", when the pin is correct. Here you see the useeffect function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated === true) {
      props.history.push("/chat");
    }
  }, [props.history, isAuthenticated]);
```

The isAuthenticated variable is coming from react context and is changed by the following reducer:

```
import { CHATID_FETCH_SUCCESSFUL, NEW_CURRENT_NODE_CREATED } from "./authTypes";

export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHATID_FETCH_SUCCESSFUL:
      return {
        isAuthenticated: true,
        chatId: action.payload,
      };
    // action 5: new current Node created
    case NEW_CURRENT_NODE_CREATED:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentNode: [...action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Whenever it turns to the "/chat" side, it should call the following two functions, which are currently called 10 times but should only be called once:

```
let startEvent = fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow(
        someParameters
      );
let frageEvent = fetchEventAnswerFromDialogflow(
        someParameters
      );
```

Comment: remove `props.history` from `useEffect` deps (`history` changed after each `history.push`)

Comment: you mean like this? --> `useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated === true) {
      props.history.push("/chat");
    }
  }, [ isAuthenticated]);`   it seems that this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, the problem is connected with useEffect's deps. You don't need to add `props.history` dependency.
If you add it, useEffect will be called every time `props.history` will change his value (that's the reason why you got so many re-rendering).
So your code becomes:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (isAuthenticated === true && props.history.location.pathname !== "/chat") {
  props.history.push("/chat");
}
}, [isAuthenticated]);
```

Comment: Thanks Giovanni, but it looks like it can't stop from calling the "/chat" module a lot of times

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer putting a check before call `props.history.push("/chat");`. Basically what I'm doing is check if current history location is "/chat" and in this case, skip history push. What do you think?